# Lookup for access list value from another site in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Look up for getting one list value from one site to another site

Comment: Google for "sharepoint cross site lookups"

Comment: Maybe this is a perfectly valid question, it just needs to be worded better. Narasimha, can you explain in more detail what you want to do? Are you using a SharePoint Designer workflow or are you trying to accomplish something using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question points to creating a column in a SharePoint's list and making it a lookup value i.e. its value will come from another list in another site.

As far as I know, that's not possible from the UI.

But one idea could be to trap an event when an item is being added and programatically display those values from the other site. Would that work?

Comment: How about: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Create-a-SharePoint-Lookup-Column-to-Another-Site.aspx  ?